# How to choose printer when using chromiums headless and kiosk-printing?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, printing, chromium

I want to use chromium to print html to a specific printer. I am currently using chromiums binary with the following command line switches: `--headless` and `--kiosk-printing`. I can't however choose which printer it uses. I need to do that on linux and windows. Setting the default printer by hand is not an option since I want to automate the printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the only way is to use the Chrome/Chromium switch of
[--use-system-default-printer](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/),
so as to use the system default printer.

The long-running bug report
[Issue 31395: Default printer selection and its printer settings in user preferences](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31395)
didn't get any better answer from the Chromium team.